# No me realiza búsqueda correcta, omite algunos registros según la búsqueda - Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

tengo la siguientes tablas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla **category_area** se relaciona los ID de otra tabla llamada **category** y adicionalmente de una tabla llamada **área**

la tabla **categoryAreaUser** se relaciona el ID del la tabla **usuarios** y a la vez el ID de la tabla **category_area**

La tabla de **registeractivities** se guarda el ID de usuarios y el ID de la tabla **category_area**

lo que quiero hacer es según el usuario logueado "en este caso el usuario va ser **478**" que pertenece a la tabla categoryAreaUser va a mostrar los registros de la tabla registrosactividades según el id_category_area que este asociado, adicionalmente estoy mostrando los registro que corresponde a cada usuario logueado "**478**" según el id_user.

Obtengo el id del usuario logeado y se lo paso a una variable **id_user**

```
$this->id_user = auth()->user()->id;
```

Luego realice la siguiente consulta

```
$this->idcategoryareas = categoryAreaUser::where('id_user', $this->id_user)->pluck('id_category_areas');
$registeractivities = Registeractivity::orwhereIn('id_category_areas', $this->idcategoryareas)->orwhere('id_user', $this->id_user);
```

luego la pinte en la vista

```
return view('livewire.registeractivity.live-register-activity-table',[
                'registeractivities' => $registeractivities
                ->where('des_c_activity', 'like', "%{$this->search}%")
                ->orderBy($this->sort, $this->direction)
                ->paginate($this->perPage),
            ]);
```

como queda el render

```
public function render()
{
    //ID actual de usuario logeado
    $this->id_user = auth()->user()->id;
    $this->id_area = auth()->user()->id_area;

    $this->idcategoryareas = categoryAreaUser::where('id_user', $this->id_user)->pluck('id_category_areas');
    $registeractivities = Registeractivity::orwhereIn('id_category_areas', $this->idcategoryareas)->orwhere('id_user', $this->id_user);

    return view('livewire.registeractivity.live-register-activity-table', [
        'registeractivities' => $registeractivities
            ->where('des_c_activity', 'like', "%{$this->search}%")
            ->orderBy($this->sort, $this->direction)
            ->paginate($this->perPage),
    ]);
}
```

las prueba que echo funciona bien, no se si toque cambiar algo

El problema viene es que tengo un buscador `->where('des_c_activity', 'like', "%{$this->search}%")`, al realiza una búsqueda me esta omitiendo algunos registros segun la busqueda

Si busco **a** el me muestra **a** y **b**

Si busco **b** el me muestra solo **b**

Si busco **c** el me muestra **b** y **c**

No se que hacer ya intente de muchas manera pero el problema creo que esta es al aplicar el `or` en las consultas

Comment: ¿Puedes redactar mejor el enunciado de la búsqueda por favor?, adicional si agregas la salida esperada ayudaría aún mas, de favor

Comment: Así mismo si puedes explicar la relación entre las tablas que muestras ayudaría mucho

Comment: @BetaM ya realice la actualización del post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo pude resolver pasando la consulta a un scope

en controlador deje

```
public function render()
{

        $registeractivities = Registeractivity::Consulta();

        return view('livewire.registeractivity.live-register-activity-table',[
            'registeractivities' => $registeractivities
            ->where('des_c_activity', 'like', "%{$this->search}%")
            ->orderBy($this->sort, $this->direction)
            ->paginate($this->perPage),
        ]);
 
}
```

En el modelo deje

```
public function scopeConsulta ($query )
{

    $this->id_user = auth()->user()->id;
    $this->idcategoryareas = categoryAreaUser::where('id_user', $this->id_user)->pluck('id_category_areas');
    return $query->orwhereIn('id_category_areas', $this->idcategoryareas)->orwhere('id_user', $this->id_user);
}
```

por algún motivo al dejar la consultas en el render directamente ocaciona el conflicto